# Check for new records (unusual scenario)

Tags: vb.net, datatable, compare

I need to check if a new record was added to a table.
My issues are:

1. I cannot read the whole table but only a "report" containing last 25
   records (I mean 25 last added lines);
2. Each new line is added at the
   top of the report.

My idea is to take the last 2/3 rows from my table and look for them into the report.
So, if I find them at the top, nothing was added but, if I find them from 3rd to 5th rows it means that 2 new rows were added.

I want to highlight that there is a date field. So I can use it to prevent updating errors.

Then here are my questions:

1. Is there a better logic to do what I want?
2. using this logic I have some doubts on how to code.

I need to choose:

- using a `for-next` loop on data field looking for the last data into my table and then compare the remaining fields;
- get both the report and my table into DataTables and compare each row using `Equals` (but I'm not sure that on same content the code will always return 'True');
- Using `datatable.Select` to find my last inserted row into the report (after putting it into a datatable) but I don't know how to retrieve the 'found row' position.

Any tip is apprecciated.

Comment: What do you mean by Report? What object/type is it? Which database are you using? SQL?

Comment: @AlexB. The report is into an Html table. My DB is MySql but I don't think this is important because my problem is to get new lines using vb.net not to insert them into my DB

Comment: The DB is highly relevant since you could have a hierarchical, object relational, NoSQL... Anyway Im checking your concern

Answer (score 1):

Use a data table to store report items:

```
   'Initial DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable("MyTable")
    dt.Columns.Add("MyValue", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", GetType(DateTime))
```

Simulate initial report state:

```
    'Initital data of your report
    Dim input = <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>2016-01-01</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td>2016-01-02</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    For Each x In input...<tr>
        dt.Rows.Add(Double.Parse(x.<td>(0).Value), DateTime.Parse(x.<td>(1).Value))
    Next

    '......
```

Simulate one new added report row. The second row remains unchanged:

```
    'One new record added to report
    Dim input2 = <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>31</td>
                         <td>2016-02-15</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>11</td>
                         <td>2016-01-01</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
```

Important to use Select only once, not in a loop:

```
    'Order table by MyValue,MyDate to be able to find rows
    Dim dv = New DataView(dt, "", "MyValue,MyDate", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

    For Each x In input2...<tr>
        Dim myVal As Double = Double.Parse(x.<td>(0).Value)
        Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(x.<td>(1).Value)

        'Find is faster than Select
        If dv.Find({myVal, myDate}) >= 0 Then
            'Existing record, 2nd row
        Else
            'new record, 1st row
        End If
    Next
```

Be aware that I dind´t include any exception handling / validation which you should add for production code.

Comment: I'm not able to use `dv.Find({myVal, myDate})`. Do I need any `Imports`? I only can use `dv.Rows.Find('PrimayKey')` but I don't have a primary key!

Comment: There is no property 'DataView.Rows` so are you sure your `dv` is of Type DataView and NOT DataTable? Also this code is .net 4.5. No special imports.

Comment: Sorry I was using it on a DataTable. Now I'm testing

Comment: I was forced to use a different solution but you gave me a big help. Thanks (+1)